# Why does the first one always brek on $rootScope.$apply?

Tags: angularjs

I have an itteration like this that adds some values to the rootScope inside a service:

```
$rootScope.language = {};

phraces.forEach(function(phrace){
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        $rootScope.language[phrace.name] = phrace.value;
    });
});
```

I get the following error for the first itteration:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at Error (native)
    at file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:6:450
    at m (file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:96:353)
    at h.$apply (file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:103:31)
    at file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/main.js:28:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/main.js:27:13
    at file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:66:351
    at C (file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:92:375)
    at C (file:///Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/spreadsheet2angular/js/vendor/angular.min.js:92:375)
```

The rest of the itterations work as desierd!

Full js:

```
angular.module('spreadsheet2angular', []).
    controller('Language', function(spreadsheet2angular){

    }).
    service('spreadsheet2angular', ['$http', '$rootScope',
        function($http, $rootScope){

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://cors.io/spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values?alt=json'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.language = {};
                var entries = data.feed.entry;
                var phraces = [];
                entries.forEach(function(entry){
                    var cell =  entry.gs$cell;
                    if(!phraces[cell.row]){
                        phraces[cell.row] = {};
                    }
                    if(cell.col == 1)
                    {
                        phraces[cell.row].name = cell.$t;
                    }
                    else if(cell.col == 2)
                    {
                        phraces[cell.row].value = cell.$t;
                    }
                });
                phraces.forEach(function(phrace){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        $rootScope.language[phrace.name] = phrace.value;
                    });
                });
                console.log($rootScope.language);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error');
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: Can you show where this code is placed?  have you tried to run it without $apply?

Comment: much text, very javascript!

Comment: inside a service ? it's not the angular way and it's strictly forbidden :)

Comment: which is? Adding values to a scope?

Comment: I'm fairly new to angular, I wondered where I ought to put this code. It retrievs some values and adds them to the a scope.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it without $apply:

```
phraces.forEach(function(phrace){
  $rootScope.language[phrace.name] = phrace.value;
});
```

---

$http already triggers a digest upon resolve, see the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.10/src/ng/http.js#l975):

```
function done(status, response, headersString) {

    // some code

    if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply(); // yeah!
  }
```

Comment: do you put $rootScope in a service ? doing you violate encapsulation

Comment: @Whisher No, I don't, but this is not directly related to the topic of the question. I only answered to why the digest in progress error happens and how to fix it. It also depends on how the application is structured and where that model needs to be injected.